# Vlookup Bucketing Issue with Percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Excel's Vlookup's functionality to bucket/categorize values has been quite helpful but I'm running into an issue when attempting to bucket %s (factional numbers). My formula below is outputting "Watermelon" when it should output "Apple".

Does anyone know why that is? What's an easy fix? Thanks for reading.

Vlookup(2.4%,table,2,1)

My value: 2.4%

2% | Apple

1% | Orange

.1%| Watermelon

Comment: For approximate_match to work the data must be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: May be coz the formula is unable to **find the closest match**  you are Struggling to get the correct result ! Try this,, `{=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF(A2:A7<C2,A2:A7)),A2:B7,2,FALSE)}` Put `2.4%` in cell `C2`.